# Akka http match path

Tags: scala, path, akka-http

I have a case where I want to validate something only for a particular route i.e. end with "_xxx" . But if I do the way its shown below then pathSuffix extract the path and leaves a suffix unmatched suffix in the route object and hence can not be used by caller of this function as the route object is changed.

```
def apply(route: Route): Route =
    pathSuffix("_xxx") {
      extractRequest { request =>
          entity(as[SomeObject]) { content =>
            if (content.records.size > limit)
              complete(
                StatusCodes.BadRequest -> "msg"
              )
            else
              route // talking about this.
          }
      }
    }
```

Can I have a way to execute this piece of code for only those uri path that ends with "_xxx" and  if the condition does not satisfy then return original route so it can be used further !!

Answer (score 0):

you can apply a pattern matching as:

```
object routeSuffix {
   def unapply(arg: String): Boolean = arg.endsWith("_xxx")
}

if (content.records.size > limit)
   complete(
      StatusCodes.BadRequest -> "msg"
   )
else {
  route match {
    case routeSuffix() => // what you want to do 
    case _ => // default case, do nothing or anything else
  }
}
```

Comment: AllexXyS the issue is, I want to execute `if (content.records.size > limit)
   complete(
      StatusCodes.BadRequest -> "msg"
   )`
for only those routes that ends with "_xxx" , but the solution you provided, that piece of code will execute for all routes.

Comment: How routeSuffix is taking string argument ? how is  it getting URI ?

Comment: This is a pattern matching. routeSuffix take only an argument and pass it to unapply method (arg - which in this case is type String). If your route (which is type String) match the pattern (endsWith("_xxx")), then, will go into this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
def apply(route: Route): Route =
    extractRequest {
      case HttpRequest(POST, Uri.Path("dsd/_xxx"), _, _, _) =>
        entity(as[SomeObject]) { content =>
          if (content.records.size > limit)
            complete(
              StatusCodes.BadRequest -> "msg"
            )
          else
            route
        }
      case _ => route
    }
```